Lancom Failover Configuration does not use LTE after following their documentation
I have tried to configure a Lancom 1900EF-5G Firewall. It is running the latest firmware (10.80.0450SU4). I want to configure SD WAN Dynamic Path Selection. I have three ISP connections. Two fiber connections which are configured as a load balancer. I have an LTE connection which I want to switch over to if both fiber fails.
I followed documentation from Lancom. It does not appear to work with the following settings:

Firewall settings

Firewall source LOCALNET dest ANY, Prio 9999
Firewall IPv4 Rule dynamic path selection session switch over checked
Load balancer policy: LOW-LATENCY


IP Router

Load Balancing enabled, client binding checked, site 1: Fiber1, site 2: Fiber2


SD-WAN Dynamic Path Selection

Policy assignment: Low-latency, load balancer: main, 1: Fiber1, 2: Fiber2, 3: LTE, Switchover: AGGRESSIVE-SWITCHOVER



Here are my questions:

How can I validate or test the configuration?
Do I need the LTE in the existing load balancer?
Low latency doesn't seem to be what I want for load balancing. Is there something different I can use?

